# Set environment variables for spawned subprocesses

Tags: process, subprocess, environment, call-process

I would like to set the environment variables for a spawned subprocess only.
They are controlled by `process-environment`. The documentation says:

> binding that variable with let is also reasonable practice.

In this example I try to unset `HOME` with:

```
(defun f()
  (let ((old-home (getenv  "HOME")))
    (let* ((process-environment process-environment)
       (process-environment (setenv-internal process-environment  "HOME" nil nil)))
      (start-process "proc" nil "notepad"))
    (string= old-home (getenv  "HOME"))))

(f)
```

`(f)` returns `nil` and `process-environment` is permanently changed (outside the `let*`).

Another thing, that happens when debugging, is that concurrent processes using `HOME` (for example Emacs autosave hooks) might fail crashing the debug session.

An alterative would be to use two `setenv`s before and after `start-process`. It still would not solve the conflict with concurrent processes (and does not explain how to use `process-environment` inside a `let`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setenv-internal` and `setenv` change the list stored in `process-environment` (as local or special variable) by side-effects.

It does not help if you assign the list (pointer) to a local variable `process-environment`. You still have only a single list for the process-environment which is just bound to two variables -- the global variable `process-environment` and the `let`-bound variable `process-environment`. If you modify that single list by side-effect, it effects all processes that use that list as process environment regardless to which variables the list is bound.

To get separate process environments for all processes you must create a copy of `process-environment` for the `let`-binding, e.g. with `cl-copy-list`.

```el
(defun f()
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((old-home (getenv  "HOME"))
      (process-environment (cl-copy-list process-environment)))
      (setenv "HOME" nil)
      (start-process "proc" (current-buffer) "emacs" "--batch" "--eval" "(prin1 (concat \"proc gets \" (getenv-internal \"HOME\" initial-environment)))" "--kill")
      (message "HOME within the let: %s" (getenv  "HOME")))
    (message "HOME after the let: %s" (getenv "HOME"))
    (buffer-string)))
(f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still wonder if I can have the `setenv` affecting only the given process and avoid conflicts with concurrent processes. For example, consider the autosave hook starting while `HOME` is unset/modified and the save path uses `~`.

Comment: @antonio I have added some sentences that hopefully make crystal clear that `cl-copy-list` avoid effects across processes through `process-environment`.

Comment: `(getenv-internal \"HOME\" initial-environment)` won't really give the initial environment value of HOME on Windows prior to Emacs 25.2 (see [Bug#10980](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10980)).

Answer (score 3):

Since Emacs 28.1 you can use the `with-environment-variables` macro.

Example:

```lisp
(with-environment-variables (("DESKTOP_SESSION" "TEST_VALUE"))
  (shell-command "echo $DESKTOP_SESSION"))
(shell-command "echo $DESKTOP_SESSION")
```

Output:

```
TEST_VALUE
ubuntu
```

Answer (score 2):

The "let binding" way is the following (notice that contrary to Tobias's answer, this does not involve any copying or "set"ting):

```
(let ((process-environment
       (cons "HOME"
             (cons (concat "OLDHOME=" (getenv "HOME"))
                   process-environment))))
  (start-process "proc" (current-buffer) ...))
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `(cons "HOME"` part only has the desired effect in Emacs 25.1 or newer, due to [Bug#23779](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23779).

Comment: @npostavs Thanks. I had almost the same solution as Stefan (only the OLDHOME-thing was a bit different) but I discarded it because it did not work for me. Your comment disclosed why.