# Change $PATH once emacs is running

Tags: variables, environment

In my shell (`Bash`), I can switch among several `LaTeX` distros setting the `$PATH` variable. E.g.:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

This doesn't affect the `LaTeX` distro used by emacs when I call the function `tex-file`.

Is there a way to set the `$PATH` variable used by emacs once it is running.

I need it to test the `.pdf` file layout generated by different `LaTeX` distros while working on a document.

Comment: From `emacs` you can call `setenv` and then modify `PATH` as you need, which should have the effect you desire.  If this works for your use case, you could probably write a small elisp function to ease the switching between various `texlive` distributions

Comment: @einfeyn496 Ok, I just noticed that changing the value of PATH does't have effect on the `Latex` distro used by `emacs`. Your answer is right, my question was wrong. if you deem it appropriate you can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs initialises <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `exec-path` based on `PATH` at start-up, and finds executables based upon that.

> This doesn't affect the LaTeX distro used by emacs when I call the function `tex-file`.

Try this:

```el
(let ((exec-path (cons "/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux"
                       exec-path)))
  (tex-file))
```

---

Note that `exec-path` is not automatically copied into the environment inherited by other processes started by Emacs; so if the executable ultimately called by `tex-file` itself *also* required `PATH` to contain `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux` then you would need to set `process-environment` as well:

```el
(let* ((tex "/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux")
       (exec-path (cons tex exec-path))
       (process-environment (cons (format "PATH=%s:%s"
                                          tex (getenv "PATH"))
                                  process-environment)))
  (tex-file))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `emacs` function [`setenv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Environment.html) is a way to modify the environment of the running `emacs` process.

For your particular use case, you'd want to evaluate:

```
(setenv PATH "modified-path-variable")
```

or simply <kbd>M-x</kbd> `setenv` and enter the value at the prompt.

You can put together an `elisp` function following the answers [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41738/set-environment-variables-for-spawned-subprocesses), to quickly toggle between your `texlive` distributions.

Or you can probably do the same using the answer from @phils

Comment: Throws: "Lisp error: (void-variable PATH)"